# how to edit album/photo description in facebook?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook

i create app based ruby on rails
i'm using fb_graph gem
wheter possible to edit message in album or photo??
how?
thx

Answer (score 0):

I'm nov, fb_graph developer.

I don't think Facebook Graph API support "edit" feature.